# delete a part of a string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I tried to delete a part of a text if i press on a button.

So what i did:

```
<div "topbar">
    hey there! <div class="close" id="topbar_search_close">remove this button</div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
document.getElementById("topbar").innerHTML -= '<div class="close" id="topbar_search_close">&times;</div><div class="search_main">';
```

Is there an alternative? Thank you!

Comment: The `-=` operator is a numeric subtraction operator.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can't subtract strings. Are you trying to replace the string, or remove it entirely?

Comment: And your HTML is incomplete: `<div "topbar">`. http://jsfiddle.net/m3esahgu/

Comment: i want to remove the secound part of the string. so that after pressing the button you just the "hey there!"

Answer (score 0):

This should remove all the children nodes from the element.

```
document.getElementById("topbar").empty();
```

If you're trying to just change the text and you know what the text is.

```
document.getElementById("topbar").text = "some new text";
```

If it's something different, then please be more specific on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To remove part of the string you could use `String.prototype.replace` like so:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('topbar_search_close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var topbar = document.getElementById('topbar');
    topbar.innerHTML = topbar.innerHTML.replace('<div class="close" id="topbar_search_close">remove this button</div>', '');
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  hey there!
  <div class="close" id="topbar_search_close">remove this button</div>
</div>
```

But this is a bad idea to remove DOM Nodes. You could simply remove it like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('topbar_search_close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var node = e.target; //topbar_search_close
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  hey there!
  <div class="close" id="topbar_search_close">remove this button</div>
</div>
```